# Query Related to Python - Folders Read

Tags: python

I want to read folders in python and probably make a list of it. Now my main concern is that most recent folder should be at location that is known to me. It can be the first element or last element of list. I am attaching image suggesting folders name. I want folder with name 20181005 either first in the list or last in the list.

I have tried this task and used os.listdir, but I am not very much confident on the way this function reads folders and store in list form. Would it store first folder as element or will it use creation date or modification date. If I could sort on the basis of name (20181005 etc), it would be really good.

Kindly suggest suitable method for the same.

Regards
[image]

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir returns directory contents in arbitrary order, but you can sort that yourself:

`l = sorted(listdir())`

Since it seems that your folder names are ISO dates, they should sort correctly and the most recent one should be the last element after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access creation & modification times you can do that with `os.path` functions. If you want to sort by that, I would probably choose to put it in something like a pandas DataFrame to make it easier to manipulate.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

path = "."
objects = os.listdir(path)
dirs = list()

for o in objects:
    opath = os.path.join(path, o)
    if os.path.isdir(opath):
        dirs.append(dict(path=opath,
                         mtime=datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(opath)),
                         ctime=datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(opath))))

data = pd.DataFrame(dirs)
data.sort_values(by='mtime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed, your directories has YYYYMMDD  format naming. Then you can use listdir and sort to get the latest directory in last index.

```
import os
from os import listdir
mypath = 'D:\\anil'
list_dirs = []
for f in listdir(mypath):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(mypath, f)):
        list_dirs.append(f)
list_dirs.sort()
for current_dir in list_dirs:
    print(current_dir)
```

Comment: @mohchu if it is working, please mark this as answer. Thanks for replay.